# How to display contenteditable contents properly? (laravel) (vue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, contenteditable, laravel-6

I have done saved the contents inside the `#descrition` below.

```
<div id="description" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

My problem is when I try to display it does not display like an html format, it displays same like the saved data with `<h1></h1>` & `<br>`. It displays plain text only.

```
<div id="description" contenteditable="true">{{ $description }}</div>
```

---

The content I saved in my database & display:

```
<h1>Descriptoin</h1> Doner, where I built and maintained banner adverts and microsites. <br> And...
```

Someone know how to display this properly?

---

**Answer:** thanks to @Akram Wahid

In laravel - `{!! $description !!}`
In vue - `<div v-html="description"> </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do like this , because Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks.If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
<div id="description" contenteditable="true">{!! $description !!}</div>
```

Comment: answer is correct. cant accept need to wait 10mins. Bdw Sir you know how to achieve this in `html/css` solution because nxt week I will use **vue** for this just extra ask :). I mean vue does not recognize `{!! !!}`

Comment: in vue, you have to do like this , `<div v-html="yourdataproperty"> </div>`

Comment: perfectly working. thank you Sir. Searching so long for this answer :).

Answer (score 1):

By default Laravel escape special characters to prevent XSS attack.
Try using this format:

```
<div id="description" contenteditable="true">{!! $description !!}</div>
```

Comment: You can do something like this: `<div v-html="description"> </div>`